# How to block custom properties from being edited by the user?

Tags: python, properties

I'm creating a custom property for each object in my scene but don't want the user to be able to edit it. Is it possible to block the property in ui ?
Here is my code :

```
import bpy

allObjects = list(bpy.data.objects)

for element in allObjects:
    element["myProp"] = "My value"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might create a [custom property](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.props.html) and pass only a get method:

```
import bpy

#default getter
def get_my_prop(self):
    return self['my_prop']

#omit the setter with a given getter to make it read-only
bpy.types.Object.my_prop = bpy.props.StringProperty(get=get_my_prop)

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    #assign the value directly
    obj['my_prop'] = "My Value"
```

It looks like this in the properties panel in blender 2.71:
[image: getter]

Comment: That works very well but when I close and open the blend file, the custom property is editable again. I tried to use the options={'HIDDEN'} in my stringProperty but it doesn't hide my property...

Comment: How can I keep the property not editable by the user from a session to another? I don't need to have it visible in the interface.

Comment: You can either check the `Register` option in the text editor to run the script when the blend file is loaded or create an addon. [#1](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/info_overview.html#script-loading) [#2](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/info_tutorial_addon.html#addon-tutorial)

Comment: In order to run the script upon scene loading, you could add your function in a permanent handler, with an @persistent decorator, as seen here: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_6/bpy.app.handlers.html
This way, when you load a scene, the script runs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I was not satisifed with the way the field is dimmed and the value can't be accessed in a color field when it is read-only.

I added custom `get` and `set` methods to ensure the user can't modify it from the interface, while being able to click the field and copy the values inside the RGB widget.

```
import bpy


bpy.types.Object.my_prop = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
    subtype="COLOR", 
    set=lambda s, c: None, 
    get=lambda s: s["my_prop"], 
    min=0, 
    max=1
)


for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj["my_prop"] = (0.5, 0.3, 0.2)
```

[image]

You can still change the property with a custom Hex value using the interface, but I guess this is managed differently so I don't know how to prevent that. You can also change the HSV sliders but the changes will be discarded when you exit the widget.